# C++: Overloading addition operator for a variable that has multiple arguments

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the addition operator. What I am trying to achieve is that when `item1 + item2` are added together the number of `units_sold` adds and revenue is added. In this example, I am assuming that the ISBNs are the same for the entries. I don't show checking this in the code below but I do so in the actual code. That is, the ISBN don't add but remain unchanged in the output.

The problem code:

```
Sales_data Sales_data::operator + (const Sales_data & data1, const Sales_data   
                                   & data2) {  
  return Sales_data(data1.units_sold + data2.units_sold);                       
  return Sales_data(data1.revenue + data2.revenue);
}
```

I am not sure if I can't use two returns like this but wasn't sure how I would get multiple adds for the components of the `Sales_data` variables. Here is a complete example illustrating the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Sales_data {                                                             
  std:: string bookNo;                                                          
  unsigned units_sold = 0;                                                      
  double revenue = 0.0;                                                         
};

// overload istream in order for cin to work                                    
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream & in, Sales_data & cSales_data) { 
in >> cSales_data.bookNo >> cSales_data.units_sold >> cSales_data.revenue;    
return in;
}

// overload ostream in order for cout to work                                   
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & out,
                           const Sales_data & cSales_data) { 
out << cSales_data.bookNo << ", " << cSales_data.units_sold << ", "  
    << cSales_data.revenue;                     
return out;         
}    

// addition operator rules                                                      
Sales_data Sales_data::operator + (const Sales_data & data1, const Sales_data   
                                   & data2) {  
  return Sales_data(data1.units_sold + data2.units_sold);                       
  return Sales_data(data1.revenue + data2.revenue);
}

int main() {
  Sales_data, item1, item2, total;
  std::cin >> item1 >> item2 >> std::endl;
  total = item1 + item2;
  std::cout << total << std::endl;
}
```

The error message I am receiving is

```
error: ‘Sales_data Sales_data::operator+(const
Sales_data&, const Sales_data&)’ must take either zero or one argument
                                    & data2) {
                                           ^
In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are
‘Sales_data’ and ‘Sales_data’)
     total = item1 + item2;
```

From the messages, I have tried `data1()` and `data2()` where I am attempting to overload the addition operator, and in the same section of code, I tried `const Sales_data()` but that doesn't seem to do it either.

I have also tried `Sales_data & Sales_data::operator+` as well but that produces the same error.

How can I overload `operator+` for `Sales_data` correctly?

Comment: `operator+` operates on exactly two items: `x + y` adds `x` to `y`, and produces a single result. If you need to represent two things in the result, you need to return a single item (e.g., a `struct`) containing both items you care about.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I don't understand/know how I would accomplish that or what terms I should search for to see relevant examples.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very helpful in this case:

```
error: ‘Sales_data Sales_data::operator+(const
Sales_data&, const Sales_data&)’ must take either zero or one argument
                                    & data2) {
```

There are two `operator+`s: the unary one (i.e. `+x`) and the binary one (i.e. `a + b`). The *member* operator overload versions of those take zero and one argument, respectively - whereas the definition that you wrote takes two arguments. That is the error: it's an invalid signature.

I'm guessing that you really intended to write a normal non-member binary `operator+`, so the `Sales_data::` is superfluous and an error. The correct operator would be:

```
Sales_data operator +(const Sales_data& data1, const Sales_data& data2)
{  
    assert(data1.bookNo == data2.bookNo);
    return Sales_data{data1.bookNo, 
                      data1.units_sold + data2.units_sold,
                      data1.revenue + data2.revenue};
}
```

As a *member* operator, the `data1` argument would be replaced by the implicit `this`:

```
struct Sales_data {
    ...
    Sales_data operator+(const Sales_data& data);
};

Sales_data Sales_data::operator+(const Sales_data& data2) {
    assert(bookNo == data2.bookNo);
    return Sales_data{bookNo, 
                      units_sold + data2.units_sold,
                      revenue + data2.revenue};
}
```

Comment: Neither your answer or Mooing Duck's answer worked alone; however, using different parts of the setup from both of your answers did work.

Answer (score 1):

First: there are two ways to declare binary `operator+`, and you've made a mix of the two of them:

```
class Sales_data {
     ///select ONE of these two

     friend Sales_data operator+(const Sales_data& lhs, const Sales_data& rhs); 
     //is a 'friend' function: there is no 'this'.  Has two parameters.

     Sales_data operator+(const Sales_data& rhs) const; 
     //'this' is the left side.  Has one parameter, and is const
};
```

As for the return, why are you returning?  You want to return a new `Sales_data` that has both of those things added.  Normally, it's done like this:

```
class Sales_data {
    //implement BOTH of these two
    Sales_data& operator+=(const Sales_data& rhs); //plus equals
    friend Sales_data operator+(const Sales_data& lhs, const Sales_data& rhs);
};
Sales_data& Sales_data::operator+=(const Sales_data& rhs) {
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
    revenue += rhs.revenue;
    return *this;
}
Sales_data operator+(const Sales_data& lhs, const Sales_data& rhs) {
    Sales_data result(lhs); //result is copy of lhs
    result += rhs; //plus rhs
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Neither your answer or Barry's answer worked alone; however, using different parts of the setup from both of your answers did work.

Comment: @dustin: Both our answers are complete.  Most likely you made a typo or oversight.